# CMake does not find MPI for Fortran

Tags: cmake, fortran, mpi, archlinux, openmpi

CMake does not find MPI for Fortran.

I am on Arch Linux with CMake 3.19.2.
I installed the openmpi (4.0.5-2) package and as stated [here](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/openmpi/) I also installed the gcc-fortran (10.2.0-4) package for fortran support.

I my CMake script in the line where MPI should be found:

```
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
```

it tells me that it could not find MPI for Fortran:

```
-- Found MPI_C: /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi.so (found version "3.1")                                        
-- Found MPI_CXX: /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi_cxx.so (found version "3.1")                                  
-- Could NOT find MPI_Fortran (missing: MPI_Fortran_WORKS) 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_Fortran_FOUND) (found version "3.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:582 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1721 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:387 (find_package)
```

When installing openmpi it tells me that fortran support should be enabled:

```
(2/2) installing openmpi

Optional dependencies for openmpi
    gcc-fortran: fortran support [installed]
```

There is a file /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi_mpifh.so. Correct me if I am wrong but I think this should be the correct library file.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT**

I just tried to build a minimal example:

```
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
enable_language(Fortran)           
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
```

With this it finds MPI_Fortran

```
-- Found MPI_Fortran: /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi_usempif08.so (found version "3.1")
```

The CMakeLists.txt is a rather long and legacy one...
Seems that I have to find the solution on my own.

Comment: It works for me on Arch Linux with the same package versions as yours. Check that `/usr/lib/openmpi/mpi.mod` exists and that you are not setting some strange value to `FC`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. As said in the edit of the answer this is legacy cmake and not written by myself.

My fortran skills are not too advanced so I do not know why this is used but the following line did break the finding process of the library:

```
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -heap-arrays 0")
```

If anyone falls into the same trap try to avoid this!

Comment: "-heap-arrays" is an Intel Fortran compiler flag. You should likely fence it with some if block, to be added and used only when Intel ifort is being used. GFortran will likely not recognize this flag. That might be the reason for the issue you have encountered. Other than this, "-heap-arrays 0" simply puts all memory allocations on the heap rather than stack: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/advanced-optimization-options/heap-arrays.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll add a comment in the CMake script!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `COMPONENTS` keyword on the `find_package` command, e.g.

```
find_package(MPI REQUIRED COMPONENTS Fortran)
```

Be sure you have Fortran enabled in your CMakeLists.txt either by enabling it in the project command, i.e.

```
project(name LANGUAGES Fortran)
```

or by calling

```
enable_language(Fortran)
```

prior to `find_package`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately that did not fix the problem. Fortran was already enabled with the enable_language function. It seems that find_package(MPI) than automatically tries to find the fortran package. The errors remain the same.